# SSIS Package Running In Debug Mode Inside Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ssis, permissions

I have an SSIS Package that I am trying to execute inside Visual Studio (right mouse click and hit "execute package").It pushes stuff to SharePoint but when I run it, I get

> Access to the path is denied.

My admin says it is a permissions issue with SharePoint but I need to know which account to use to give permissions to that folder.

I assumed it was my AD login, but that doesn't seem to be it.  Would anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank all of you for the help, but I found the answer.  Our system admin came back and told me that he setup the path incorrectly and had to fix that.  Once he did that, the error went away, so the error was that the path didn't exist, not that it was a permissions issue.

My apologies for the confusion, but as I was unable to look (I do not have access), I had to rely on his information.

But thank you all for the help.  greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check which account it's using with these directions, then give access to that account: http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/09/who-is-running-package.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current user running the package from the system variable `System::Username`

Read more about ssis system variables at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables